# What are the possible causes of Lint-staged Chinese garbled characters in Windows shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, lint-staged

**environment**：windows10  node v20.10.0

**description**：If you run `lint-staged` without global installation of prettiered, an error message is reported and the output error message from the console is garbled

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.0",
},
"lint-staged": {
    "src/routes/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}": [
      "yarn prettiered"
    ]
  }
```

**The following error message is displayed：**
'prettier' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
���������ļ���

I hope we can find out the reason for the garbled code.

Comment: And if you install "prettiered", does it work?

Comment: It works, but I'd like to know why the error message is garbled and how to fix it

Comment: You fix it by installing "prettiered".  You can't run an app you haven't installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.